# Getting values from Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have the following code which gives me this output (each link is separated by ',').

```
ids = soup.find_all("tr",{"class":"table-row"})
#ids = soup.findAll("span",{"class": "text-nowrap"})
ids
```

An example of one of the links is as follows

```
                            <tr _ngcontent-sc371="" class="table-row">
                                <td _ngcontent-sc371="" class="table-col">
                                    <a _ngcontent-sc371="" data-gtm="address" class="text-primary font-weight-bolder text-left" href="/salg/info/326/25402/A5694110-6CCD-431B-B86D-D9B87CD062F6">
                                         Svalevaanget 20,
                                        <br _ngcontent-sc371="" class="d-block d-sm-none">
                                         4400 Kalundborg 
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td _ngcontent-sc371="" class="table-col text-right">
                                    <span _ngcontent-sc371="" class="mobile-heading"> Koobesom </span>
                                    <span _ngcontent-sc371="" class="text-nowrap">995.000</span>
                                </td>
                                <td _ngcontent-sc371="" class="table-col text-right">
                                    <span _ngcontent-sc371="" class="mobile-heading"> Salgsdato </span>
                                    <span _ngcontent-sc371="" class="text-nowrap">22-09-2020</span>
                                </td>
                                <td _ngcontent-sc371="" class="table-col text-right">
                                    <span _ngcontent-sc371="" class="mobile-heading"> Boligtype </span>
                                    <span _ngcontent-sc371="" class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                                        <app-property-label _ngcontent-sc371="" _nghost-sc241="">
                                            <label _ngcontent-sc241="" class="property-4 hide-text">
                                                <app-tooltip _ngcontent-sc241="" class="md-right flex-shrink-0" _nghost-sc191="">
                                                    <p _ngcontent-sc191="" class="app-tooltip">
                                                         Fritidshus <!---->
                                                        <!---->
                                                        <!---->
                                                    </p>
                                                    <!---->
                                                    <span _ngcontent-sc241="" class="icon">F</span>
                                                </app-tooltip>
                                                <span _ngcontent-sc241="" class="text">Fritidshus</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </app-property-label>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td _ngcontent-sc371="" class="table-col text-right">
                                    <span _ngcontent-sc371="" class="mobile-heading"> Kr. / m² </span>
                                    <span _ngcontent-sc371="" class="text-nowrap"> 12.134 </span>
                                </td>
                                <td _ngcontent-sc371="" class="table-col text-right">
                                    <span _ngcontent-sc371="" class="mobile-heading"> Værelser </span>
                                    <span _ngcontent-sc371=""> 3 </span>
                                </td>
                                <td _ngcontent-sc371="" class="table-col text-right">
                                    <span _ngcontent-sc371="" class="mobile-heading"> m² </span>
                                    <span _ngcontent-sc371="" class="text-nowrap"> 82 m² </span>
                                </td>
                                <td _ngcontent-sc371="" class="table-col text-right">
                                    <span _ngcontent-sc371="" class="mobile-heading"> Byggear </span>
                                    <span _ngcontent-sc371=""> 1971 </span>
                                </td>
                                <td _ngcontent-sc371="" class="table-col text-right">
                                    <span _ngcontent-sc371="" class="mobile-heading"> Prisjustering </span>
                                    <!---->
                                </td>
```

I am not sure how I proceed from here in order for me to get the values out. My aim is to store it in a DataFrame where, for instance, I have the columns names and the corresponding values (based on the link) Salgsdato (22-09-2020), address (Svalevaanget 20), Koobesom (995.000), m² (82).

Anyone with some helpful guidance?

Appreciate it.

Comment: `helpful guidance?` - [https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0):

To create Dataframe from the document and save it to CSV, you can use this example (`txt` is your HTML snippet from the question):

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

# remove mobile-headings
for mh in soup.select('.mobile-heading'):
    mh.extract()

all_values = []
for tr in soup.select('tr.table-row'):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ') for td in tr.select('td')]
    all_values.append(tds)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_values, columns=['Address', 'Koobesom', 'Salgsdato', 'Boligtype', 'Kr. / m²', 'Værelser', 'm²', 'Byggear', 'Prisjustering'])
df.to_csv('data.csv')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                            Address Koobesom  ... Byggear Prisjustering
0  Svalevaanget 20, 4400 Kalundborg  995.000  ...    1971              

[1 rows x 9 columns]
```

And creates `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]